# cin.get() function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been studying c++ and came across the code below. I dont understand why they have to use the get(c) in "cin.get(straddress, sizeof(straddress), fdelim).get(c)". The code works just fine without this get(c). Can someone enlighten me on the use of get(c)? The purpose of the program is to read data of mixed type.

```
const char fdelim = '\t';
char straddress[256];
int zip;
char c;

cout << "Enter a record of data:  ";
cin.get(straddress, sizeof(straddress), fdelim).get(c) >> zip;
cout << "\nStreet address :   " << straddress << endl;
cout << "\nZip/Postal code:   " << zip << endl;
```

Comment: That just gets the next character from the input stream and puts it in `c`.

Comment: It looks like it's just trying to skip past the TAB delimiter of the address. But that's not needed, because `>> zip` will skip over whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
cin.get(straddress, sizeof(straddress), fdelim).get(c) >> zip;
```

reads everything up to `fdelim` to `straddress`, then reads the delimiter to `c`, and then reads the zip code to `zip`.

It could have been written better as:

```
cin.get(straddress, sizeof(straddress), fdelim);
cin.get(c);
cin >> zip;
```

Since `c` is not used, it could have been ignored too.

```
cin.get(straddress, sizeof(straddress), fdelim);
cin.ignore(1); // Read and discard 1 character.
cin >> zip;
```

Comment: I guess they wrote that in case `fdelim` were changed to a non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user types in fewer than 255 characters before typing in a `\t` character, the first call to [`cin.get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) will stop reading when the `\t` character is reached, but will not extract it from `cin`.  The next call to `cin.get()` will then extract the `\t`.

I would opt to use [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) instead, which reads the delimiter but does not store it in the caller's buffer:

```
const char fdelim = '\t';
char straddress[256];
int zip;

cout << "Enter a record of data:  ";
cin.getline(straddress, sizeof(straddress), fdelim);
cin >> zip;
cout << "\nStreet address :   " << straddress << endl;
cout << "\nZip/Postal code:   " << zip << endl;
```

Even better, I would use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead, which reads into a `std::string` instead of a `char[]` buffer:

```
const char fdelim = '\t';
string straddress;
int zip;

cout << "Enter a record of data:  ";
getline(cin, straddress, fdelim);
cin >> zip;
cout << "\nStreet address :   " << straddress << endl;
cout << "\nZip/Postal code:   " << zip << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I saw your it just now. It gives me further insight. I am very grateful.